# Complete but not overcomplete subset of coherent state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, coherent-states

Define $$|z \rangle=e^{z \hat b^\dagger-z^* \hat b}|0\rangle$$
$|z\rangle$ is called [coherent state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_states), and we know $\{|z \rangle| z\in\mathbb{C}\}$ is overcomplete. So does there exist a complete but not overcomplete subset? How to construct it explicitly?

I try to restrict $z=r e^{i \theta}$ for fixed $r$ or $z\in \mathbb{R}$, but I find they are still overcomplete.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by overcomplete? It is not obvious to me. Any finite subset of the coherent states is linearly independant. On the other hand in the completeness relation the "coefficient function" is unique when chosen from the Bargmann-Segal space of holomorphic "square integrable" functions.

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka Overcomplete means that there exist some proper subset that is complete. For example $\{|z\rangle|z\in\mathbb{C} \}$ is overcomplete, becuase $\{|z\rangle|z\in\mathbb{R} \}$ is still complete. By the same reason, you will find $\{|z\rangle|z\in\mathbb{R} \}$ is also overcomplete

Comment: I would have assumed that by complete you mean that $$\psi=\pi^{-1}\int_{z\in\mathbb{C}} \langle z,\psi\rangle |z\rangle$$ for all $\psi$, but it is not true for the set with $z\in \mathbb{R}$ for example (by which I mean you can't just restrict integration above to $z\in\mathbb{R}$). What do you mean by complete?

Comment: @AdomasBaliuka any elementary discussion of coherent states will include a discussion of their overcompletedness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Complete sets of coherent states can be constructed in many ways. [Historically](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Christopher_Heil/publication/225827675_History_and_Evolution_of_the_Density_Theorem_for_Gabor_Frames/links/0c960533cb94167f1e000000.pdf), the most important examples of these complete sets are the Bargmann-Gabor frames, whose completeness was conjegtured by von-Neumann and proved by [Perelomov](https://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0210005v1) and independently by 
[Bargmann, Buerta, Giradello and Klauder](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Luciano_Girardello2/publication/222630166_On_the_completeness_of_coherent_states/links/0912f513db493b1287000000.pdf).

These proofs are known today as the coherent state density theorem.

The Bargmann-Gabor frames are sets of coherent states $|z\rangle$ corresponding to the lattice points:
$$z_{mn} = m \omega_1 + n \omega_2$$
($\omega_1$ and $\omega_2$ are not colinear).
The density theorem states that if the lattice unit cell area is greater than $\pi$ the set is not comlete, if the area is smaller than $\pi$ then it is supercomplete (contains many comlete bases) and if the area is exactly equal to $\pi$, then the set is complete and remains complete if exactly one element is removed. In the latter (complete) case, the set of coherent states is called a tight frame.

The Bargmann-Gabor frames and frames in general found many applications in mathematics (they consist the basis of the theory of wavelets), signal analysis, and physics.